# Statistics.median converting lists containing float numbers into integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, statistics

Here is a list, containing different integers, and floats, strings. I want to find the median numbers using statistics.median() but I cannot convert the list into integers.

```
#DOCTYPE Python 
import statistics
import numpy as np
data = ['3900000.00', '140000000.00', '150000000.00', '3000000.00', '189250000.00', '280000000.00', '280000000.00', '200000000.00', '2250000.00', '85000000.00', '2600000.00', '230000000.00', '680000000.00', '158000000.00', '230000000.00', '300000000.00', '200000000.00', '295000000.00', '250000000.00', '155000000.00', '143850000.00', '182000000.00', '3900000.00', '2200000.00', '91475000.00', '190000000.00', '2100000.00', '325000000.00', '118534000.00', '230000000.00', '3500000.00', '83688000.00', '320000000.00', '565000000.00', '162000000.00', '170000000.00', '265000000.00', '250000000.00', '120000000.00', '230000000.00', '88000000.00', '85000000.00', '209000000.00', '83000000.00', '161300000.00', '215000000.00', '120000000.00', '265000000.00', '167000000.00', '280000000.00', '70000000.00', '410000000.00', '215000000.00', '118000000.00', '179800000.00', '211000000.00', '131750000.00', '2400000.00', '319800000.00', '2400000.00', '140000000.00', '230000000.00', '250000000.00', '2100000.00', '137000000.00', '260000000.00', '178100000.00', '565000000.00', '160000000.00', '173000000.00', '240000000.00', '157000000.00', '176000000.00', '130000000.00', '118000000.00', '131964000.00', '85000000.00', '102268800.00', '92000000.00', '140000000.00', '148000000.00', '3200000.00', '160000000.00', '385000000.00', '140000000.00', '105000000.00', '2700000.00', '88000000.00', '129000000.00', '547950000.00', '250000000.00', '230000000.00', '138000000.00', '225000000.00', '230000000.00', '230000000.00', '230000000.00', '210000000.00', '189000000.00', '140000000.00', '328000000.00', '140000000.00', '220000000.00', '319800000.00', '85000000.00', '100000000.00', '170000000.00', '210000000.00', '2600000.00', '195000000.00', '165000000.00', '160000000.00', '195000000.00', '3800000.00', '250000000.00', '260000000.00', '230000000.00', '85000000.00', '2500000.00', '165000000.00', '86000000.00', '3900000.00', '210000000.00', '230000000.00', '434000000.00', '1600000.00', '1750000.00', '310000000.00', '165000000.00', '290000000.00', '85000000.00', '5000000.00', '380000000.00', '208000000.00', '325000000.00', '110000000.00', '40000000.00', '260000000.00', '207000000.00', '215000000.00', '450000000.00', '1600000.00', '150000000.00', '280000000.00', '220000000.00', '195975000.00', '190000000.00', '190000000.00', '297000000.00', '104100000.00', '110000000.00', '380000000.00', '270000000.00', '100000000.00', '88000000.00', '2400000.00', '2100000.00', '170000000.00', '116700000.00', '88000000.00', '155000000.00', '2400000.00', '2300000.00', '2600000.00', '120000000.00', '4000000.00', '235000000.00', '418000000.00', '125000000.00', '255000000.00', '290000000.00', '200000000.00', '233000000.00', '390000000.00', '190000000.00', '1280000000.00', '160050000.00', '285000000.00', '175000000.00', '137000000.00', '205000000.00', '126000000.00', '150000000.00', '800000000.00', '2000000.00', '160000000.00', '205000000.00', '137000000.00']

datas = ["5", "6" , "11", "1", "21", "5", "5", "5", "5", "1.00", "3.00", "5.00"]
# print([int(datas) for datas in datas])

print(int(str(datas)))
```

I have tried several methods, but I am looking for the most straight easy method.
I have been getting `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` as an error whenever i wanted to use int() method, then i tried to use str() method where float() cant be used on strings again. So i am stuck.

Comment: Your lists contain **only** strings. There are no floats or ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace:**

```
print(int(str(datas)))
```

**With:**

```
print(list(map(float,datas)))
```

**Or if you want integers not float then:**

```
print([int(float(data)) for data in datas])
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I will look into map and list functions more.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the median value from a list of numbers is trivial.

Neither of the lists in OP's question contain ints or floats - they are all strings.

The list elements should be normalised to float because some values such as '3900000.00' can't be converted [directly] to int.

Thus, if all elements in a list can be converted to float then you could implement your own median function as follows:

```
def median(_list):
    _list = sorted(map(float, _list))
    m = (ll := len(_list)) // 2
    return _list[m] if ll % 2 else (_list[m] + _list[m-1]) / 2
```

For the *data* list this will return 166000000.0 and for *datas* 5.0

Obviously the return value could just be passed to *int()* if required.

If you want to use the statistics module (which will almost certainly be faster) then:

```
from statistics import median

print(median(map(float, data)))
```